# Creating a new default css file in dreamweaver cs5.5 adds @charset "utf-8";?

Tags: dreamweaver

I am editing the default css file in dreamweaver and it almost works. The only problem i have is an extra line of code is being added. The following code is added in the first line @charset "utf-8";

But i don't see the code in Default.css??

Answer (score 1):

It's normally because you have the code `<meta charset="utf-8" />` in the html document that uses your stylesheet, and Dreamweaver (being the incredibly awesome program it is) detected that and automatically migrated it to your stylesheet.  Don't get rid of it; all it is saying is that you are saving in UTF-8 (UCS Transformation Format—8-bit) format -- the dominant character encoding for the World-Wide Web, accounting for more than half of all Web pages.  That piece of code is actually getting rid of the time the browser spends detecting the format.  Charset is your friend :)

Comment: tx but why didn't the DMW Default.css have the extra code line @charset "utf-8"; it just read `/* Css document */ And i didn't link the css file to a html file yet

Comment: I think I was wrong about it detecting the charset from a html file.  Dreamweaver is not on the machine I am typing this from, but I think there is a "encoding" option like in Notepad's "Save as" dialog, but Notepad automatically saves in ANSI.  If I recall correctly, Dreamweaver defaults to utf-8, the format most modern programs use.  It wasn't added to Default.css because not *everything* people use Dreamweaver for will be utf-8 compatible, so it doesn't add it lest some people get annoyed at Adobe for using the "wrong" format.